# How to add + and - into bootstrap collapse in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a simple accordion using bootstrap. I am using it with ul li tag with ng repeat in angularjs.
Every thing is working only just need to add + and - beside 'Collapsible list group' on expand and collapse.Here is the code below.

### html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>hello</div
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check code... if you want to put an image instead of '+ / -' you can replace '-' and '+' with image path in Javascript section and in html create a  tag and make src attribute dynamic

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.collapseStatus = '-';
  $scope.records = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]
  $scope.toggleOpen = function() {
 $scope.collapseStatus = $scope.collapseStatus == '-'? '+': '-';
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="toggleOpen()" href="#collapse1">Collapsible list group {{collapseStatus}}</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but suppose if I want to put image instead of+ and - then how to render?

Comment: in JS replace the - and + with corresponding image path and in html replace {{collapseStatus }} with <img ng-src="{{collapseStatus }}"/>

Comment: Yes I understand